# How to check if a timerange falls under an array of free slots?

Tags: php

I am after a method, that will check if a timerange, falls under some free slots.

I have a method that returns free slots in unixtime format `array['from','to']`. Visually something like:

```
07:00 - 07:45
07:45 - 08:30
14:30 - 15:15
15:15 - 16:00
```

I want to check if a given range falls under these slots. They can overlap slots, but should not span period ouf the free slot.

So valid range is:

```
07:00 - 07:45
07:00 - 08:30
07:10 - 08:20 // also valid
14:30 - 16:00 // also valid
```

Invalid range is

```
06:00 - 16:45
15:15 - 16:10
07:00 - 16:00 //there are no ranges between 8:30 and 14:30
11:00 - 12:00
```

**EDIT**

What I've so far is to check is:

```
$startsinfreeslot=true;
$endrange=0;
foreach ($arr as $slot) {
$from=$slot['from'];
$to=$slot['to'];
if ($from==$start_date && $to==$end_date) {
    // given date matches a free slot
    return true;
}
if ($start_date>=$from && $start_date<$to) {
    $startsinfreeslot=true;
    $endrange=$to;
    continue;
}

if ($startsinfreeslot) {
    // we need to check if range continues
    if ($endrange==$from) {
        // range stops in the current range
        if ($end_date<=$to) {
            return true;
        } else {
            $endrange=$to;
            continue;
        }
    } else {
        // range doesn't continued return false
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your code that you have already attempted?

Comment: Do you need to know which slots it falls under or just that it's valid?

Comment: could you show which test case your attempted code fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that the last line of your code is : return false.
Your code need to check another case that for the last free slot. If $start_date >= $from and $end_date <= $to ($from and $to is of the last slot) then your code return false. So after the loop, you should check for the last slot.